# Create same height card like flutter in native android

Tags: android, layout, flutter, height, flutter-layout

I want to create same height card UI like flutter in native android.
E.g, https://github.com/MarcinusX/bmi_calculator

Can anyone guide me how to achieve this? Just the UI

Comment: Can you add the code that you have tried and the result you are getting, as well as an image of the expected outcome. Then we'll be able to help you better.

Comment: Expected output must be same as heightcard

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MarcinusX/bmi_calculator/master/final_result.gif

Comment: @FilledStacks i am still writing the code, can you please help me more to achieve this

Answer (score -1):

Well seems like you haven't tried anything yet but it looks like simple view. Below is how the widget tree should look to achieve this.

Container

- Column

  - Row[ Height, cm]
  - Row [

    Container(Image),

    List.generate(10, (index)=>145 + index*5)

That's for the UI underneath the dragable slider. You'll put the above UI in a Stack at the back and then build your slider over that.

Comment: Thanks but can you post any example here please

For now, I created a recyclerview to show heights vertically

Comment: @AndroidGuy No I can not. Just follow the layout tree above and you should be able to make it. I'm hoping to give you a solution. Not the code itself. If you had code with your current result in your question I might see where you're going wrong and fix the code for you. But there's nothing there.